# Xcode / Swift / UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height Returning 0

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiscreen

The code below is returning 0. I've tried all the samples I can find, but it still always returns 0. I'm on XCode 9.4.1

```
    // Screen Size
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height

    NSLog("Screen Height is %i", screenHeight);
    NSLog("Screen Width is %i", screenWidth);
    // Screen Size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the statement with `print()`

```
print("Screen Height is \(screenHeight)")
print("Screen Width is \(screenWidth)")
```

In your case, `%i` is requesting an integer and `screenHeight` and `screenWidth`are floats. Therefore use `%f`

```
NSLog("Screen Height is %f", screenHeight);
NSLog("Screen Width is %f", screenWidth);
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I knew it had to be simple, but all the samples out there are like the one I posted. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

Use `print()`

```
print("Screen Height is", screenHeight)
print("Screen Width is", screenWidth)
```

or by `%f`

```
NSLog("Screen Height is %f", screenHeight)
NSLog("Screen Width is %f", screenWidth)
```